# Why does NoSuchMethodException appears when the method obviously exists?

Tags: java, exception

I have been trying to solve this problem with my code but it keeps throwing a `NoSuchMethodException` no matter what I do. Does this have to do with imports I have added?

The code is:

```
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.function.BinaryOperator;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.function.LongPredicate;
import java.util.function.Predicate;
import java.util.stream.LongStream;

public class Dishouse {
public Function<Long, Long> dionym() {
    Function<Long, Long> meth = (a) -> a - 62;
    return meth;

}

public Function<Float, Float> femality(Function<Float, Float> sorbonist) {
    Function<Float, Float> func = (a) -> a / 92;
    return func.compose(sorbonist);

}

public Optional<Long> bristler(LongStream s, Predicate<Long> p,
        BinaryOperator<Long> b) {

    LongStream result = s.filter((LongPredicate) p);
    Long count = result.count();
    long stre[] = result.toArray();
    if (count > 1) {
        Optional<Long> e = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < stre.length; i++) {
            e = Optional.of(b.apply(stre[i], stre[i + 1]));
        }
        return e;
    } else {
        return Optional.empty();
    }
}
```

The error is:

```
Method bristler not found: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Dishouse.bristler(java.util.stream.Stream, java.util.function.Predicate, java.util.function.BinaryOperator)
```

Above, I have included the whole class `Dishouse` and no other class or method interacts with this class.

Comment: Please include the code that calls `bristler()` to make the question more understandable.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't. `LongStream` isn't a `Stream`. Possibly you want `Stream<Long>` instead, which is not the same thing (one operates on primitive longs, the other operates on Long objects).

For the same reason, casting a `Predicate<Long>` to `LongPredicate` cannot work. casts just assert types, they don't convert things (unless casting to one primitive to another primitive type), and a `Predicate<Long>` isn't a `LongPredicate`.

NB: Your code can also return either `null` or `Optional.empty` or some optional which is a gigantic code smell. This isn't how you are supposed to use optional.

Answer (score 0):

`LongStream` is not a sub-interface of `Stream`. To map a `Stream<Long>` to a `LongStream`, use the following:

```
Stream<Long> sl = ...
LongStream ls = sl.mapToLong(x -> x);
```